# TFS Build Definition - Build process file showing git deleted branches

Tags: git, tfs, tfsbuild

Does anyone know why we still witness deleted git branches in the "Build process file" Process drop down, when I edit my build definition?

It is a bit of annoyance but but something that is increasing as we have more and more deleted git branches.

We are using TFS 2013 and editing them on Visual Studio 2013 update 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out a way of doing it using [community Team Build manager](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/73bf2d8e-aec6-406c-8e7f-1c678e46557f)

The extension has an drop down for Build Process Templates. YOu can right click on a template and remove it from Team project.

[image]

Comment: Thansk for the useful tool sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You just delete the branch in your local repository.The branch in drop down is on the remote(TFS server)

From Visual Studio you have two options:

1.Unpublish

2.Delete

**Unpublish** will remove the Branch tag on the remote (TFS server) and that will hide the branch from the drop down.The branch in local still exists.

**Delete** will remove the branch from your local TFS repository. It will remain on the remote (TFS Server), but you will no longer have it available in your Visual Studio's Branches window. You can get it back by creating a local branch that tracks the remote branch anew

So ,to achieve what you want, you just need to **unpubilsh the branch** or **delete the branch from remote**.

More info from Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj190809(v=vs.120).aspx (reference remove branch)

Comment: Hello,
No I deleted the branch from remote as well. Did the following
git branch -D <branchName>
git push --delete origin <branchName>

Can see that the branch is deleted as I can't see it from following
git branch -r

Comment: Have you ever try to creat a new build definition?Double check whether the delete branch is still in the drop down.